# Postfix - Html emails contain random characters

Tags: php, imap, postfix-mta

I'm storing my `postfix` emails into `mysql`.

I notice some weird characters showing up in some messages, while other emails don't have them.  So, it's random.

Here's what I see:

```
--1001534069-1142425087-1366837456=:47630
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=0A=0AConfirmation: We received your membership (one-year) p=
ayment  =0A=0A   =0A =0A =0A  =0A =0A =0A =0A=0A Confirmation:: We received =
your membership (one-year) payment=0AHi John Smith,=0AWe re=
............


--1001534069-1142425087-1366837456=:47630
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><body><div style=3D"color:#000; background-color:#fff; font-family:ti=
mes new roman, new york, times, serif;font-size:12pt"><div><br></div><div s=
tyle=3D"font-family: 'times new roman', 'new york', times, serif; font-size=
: 12pt;"><div style=3D"font-family: 'times new roman', 'new york', times, s=
erif; font-size: 12pt;"><div class=3D"y_msg_container"><div id=3D"yiv684532=
7653"><div>=0A    <div class=3D"yiv6845327653moz-forward-container">=0A    =
  =0A      <title>Confirmation: We received your membership=
............................
```

I included both content-types, and the weird characters are rather noticable.
I'm saving each email into a column type: `text`, with a Collation: `utf8_unicode_ci`

And for those interested in what I'm using to extract my postfix emails, I'm using the PHP `imap_*` functions.

Anyways, does anyone know why those weird characters get interjected?  (while other emails have perfect html or plain text?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quoted printable encoding. You need to undo the content-transfer-encoding, which might be quoted printable or base64.

Comment: You're right, after trial & error I found `quoted_printable_decode` worked for decoding it.

Comment: @coffeemonitor: blindly applying a quoted-printable decoder is a dumb thing. You have to parse the ``Content-Transfer-Encoding`` header. Also, your code appears to ignore the MIME message structure; that's also wrong. You cannot process "the email" at once, you have to focus on the individual message parts; each of them can have its own transport encoding.